# Find whichever chart object is positioned to the left of the active cell

Tags: excel, vba

The below macro changes the colour of the point in my chart to the left of the drop down (active cell). This works for the below "Chart 5", but is there a way to make it dynamic as I want the user to be able to copy paste the chart and table and change the values.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 changes the triangle colour to orange (RGB(255, 192, 0)) to indicate Amber/At Risk
Dim i As Integer

i = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value

With Worksheets("Upcoming Milestone Plan").ChartObjects("Chart 5").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
End With
    
End Sub
```

I tried to use Offset to activate the chart to the left, but it didn't work. See below. Any better suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 changes the triangle colour to purple (RGB(112, 48, 160)) to indicate End date is on On Track

Dim i As Integer

i = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value

**With Worksheets("Upcoming Milestone Plan").ChartObjects(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7))**.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(112, 48, 160)
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(112, 48, 160)
End With

    
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably need to loop through the chartobjects on the sheet and test if their [`.TopLeftCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject.topleftcell) `Intersects` with `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7)`. Or maybe [`.BottomRightCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject.bottomrightcell) depending on the position of the chartobject.

Comment: Hi BigBen, Thanks a lot. I did exactly what you advised and it worked!